# Character initialization in c language

Tags: c

I want to assign ' to a character but it keeps giving me error
any help?

```
    void main()
    {
        char c  = ''';
    }
```

Comment: `char c = '\'';`?

Comment: Yeah, you must scape the character with a backslash.

Comment: Well, in a fraction of the time taken for an SO question/answer, I would have looked up the ASCII value, loaded that instead, and moved on to the next problem.  It's a non-issue, too easily bypassed.

Comment: @MartinJames: Are you seriously suggesting people use platform-specific code for stuff that is easily done in strictly conforming c?

Comment: @MartinJames Code with `char c = '\'';` is easier to follow than `char c = 39;`

Comment: @chux: It's also portable to platforms using other encodings like EBCDIC.

Comment: Yes, such code may well fail on the millions of EBCDIC-based text systems in common use.

Comment: This OP never choose an answers, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Special characters like ' or \ must be escaped with a backslash in these situations. In this particular case you got an error because the compiler thinks you opened and closed a null character with the first two '' and then opened another character without closing it with the third one.

Comment: Did you escape the `e` in escape?

Comment: Thanks @EOF! It seems it was escaped, indeed! LOL!

Answer (score 4):

`\'` represents *Single quotation mark* in C

It is a standard [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Every time you want to assign `'`, just need to assign `\'`

Answer (score 1):

Use escape sequence:

```
char c  = '\'';
```

Also,  a double quotation mark is written as '\"' in C.

PS: No `void main()`, it should be `int main(void)`.